# Only Swapping Once?

Tags: assembly, mips

I'm trying to implement Bubblesort in MIPs. I'm so close to figuring it out, unfortunately my code only seems to swap one element in the array. My thoughts was that swap is not linked back to the loop procedures, so only one swap is performed when the subroutine to print is called. Unfortunately, I'm not that experienced in MIPs, so it's very possible that some I am jumping incorrectly. Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

[EDIT]

Adding some example output:

so [3,4,1,2,5,6] -> [3,1,4,2,5,6] and I don't know how to keep swapping till the sort is done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SPIM/MARS has debugging features that let you single-step through your code and watch the register values along the way. I suggest that you learn how to use those features.

I can see at least two problems with your code. One is that your `swap` routine never returns, so the CPU will just continue executing whatever comes after the `swap` routine. You should end `swap` with a `jr $ra`.
The other problem is that you set the `$a1` to *the address of* `length_a` before calling `sort`, but in `sort` you just do `move $s3, $a1` which will still give you `length_a`'s address rather than the value 6. That `move` should be changed to `lw $s3, ($a1)`.